# Table Format.PHP/HTML

Tags: php, html

Well I'm in a big struggle here and can't seem to figure it out so I'm going to ask here.
I have this code:

```
        <?php
            echo "<table id='teble1'>";
            while($info = mysql_fetch_array($data)) {

                echo"<tr>\r";
                echo"<td>\r";
                echo "<a href=\"".$info['Hackforums_PLink']."\">".$info ['Hackforums_UName']."</a>\r";
                echo "</td>\r";
                echo "</tr>\r";
                echo"<tr>\r";
                echo"<td>\r";
                echo "<a href=\"".$info['Osu_PLink']."\">".$info['Osu_UName']."</a>\r";
                echo"</td>\r";
                echo"</tr>\r";
            }
            echo"</table>";
        ?>
```

okay now I have the problem that Osu_PLink and Osu_UName should be listed right of Hackforums_PLink and Hackforums_UName I've tried multiply things to do this but can't make it work, it's especially confusing because of the usage of echo's.
I have never used PHP in this way and also if you know how to get table headers(Hackforums Name and Osu! Name) Please say so I really don't know how to proceed from here so could you guys help me out here?

Comment: WTF?!? Nesting <tr> tags.... please let that just be a typo

Comment: Whoops yea I was trying things with <th> as a row but probally forgot to remove the old tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write your PHP a little different.

```
       <table id='teble1'>
       <?php while($info = mysql_fetch_array($data)) : ?>
          <tr>
            <td><a href="<?php echo $info['Hackforums_PLink'] ?>"><?php echo $info ['Hackforums_UName'] ?></a></td>
            <td><a href="<?php echo $info['Osu_PLink'] ?>"><?php echo $info ['Osu_UName'] ?></a></td>
          </tr> 
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        </table>
```

Comment: Okay it sort of works only my table headers are showing up above each new cell. Any idea on how to fix this there should only be 1 row with them.

Comment: Normally I would put them outside the while loop but because the $info is only available within the while loop. I'd keep a count and put an if statement if count is equal to one then show header. Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want ??

```
            echo"<tr>";
            echo"<td>";
            echo "<a href=\"".$info['Hackforums_PLink']."\">".$info ['Hackforums_UName']."</a>";
            echo "</td>";
            echo"<td>";
            echo "<a href=\"".$info['Osu_PLink']."\">".$info['Osu_UName']."</a>\r";
            echo"</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
```

New row will always get down to previous row. So you have to put it in same row.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, you want to show both cells on the same line ? In this case, get rid of the intermediary

```
        echo "</tr>\r";
        echo"<tr>\r";
```

as they force a new row to be displayed.

Ify ou want to add table headers, just add the following before your while loop

```
echo "<tr><th><td>Hackforums Name</td><td>Osu! Name</td></th></tr>";
```

Oh and btw, mysql_fetch_array is deprecated as of PHP 5.5